# Create object if doesn't exist when calling it by related_name

Tags: django, django-models

*NOTE: I'm aware of `get_or_create` and it does not apply here.*

I have a Django app with a lot of users. One of my project apps must keep some kind of *user preferences* relating to this app, so in its' `models.py` I've created:

```
[models.py]

class UserPreferences(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='adminpanel_preferences'
    )

    advanced_options_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    force_dark_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ... (more boolean fields, integer choices etc)
```

I don't want to use signals for creating a `UserPreferences` objects every time new user is being created. My idea was to only create an object when such object is somehow requested. This might sound like a perfect `get_or_create` use case, however I need to call this object from a template using the **related_name** e.g:

```
[template.html]

{% if request.user.adminpanel_preferences.hardcore_mode_enabled %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

And while normally the `request.user.adminpanel_preferences` would return `UserPreferences.None`, I want it to silently create the object (using default field values) instead.

Is there a possibility to achieve such behavior without interfering the User model? The `UserPreferences` are not global app preferences, they only refer to this particular app and I'd love to keep these two independent.

I have also tried using a custom objects manager with customized `get_queryset` method but it doesn't seem to work when using the `related_name`.

Comment: You can use if. If your backward relationship returns none, then create. Meanwhile, isn't that Admin preferences supposed to be an iterable?

Comment: Yes. My question probably translates to "how do I override model 'get' method returning related object". The problem is that just overriding objects manager `get_queryset` method doesn't work

Comment: The template is not meant to do those stuff. Why do you want to make your own life difficult? Just create the related model when you create the user (no need for signals, just whenever you register a new user create the related model) or simply create it in the view (of whichever template needs it). Don't have the templates do such logic, it only leads to confusion later on.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to dedicate resources to create a preferences record for every user; only when one is needed. You don't want to use signals, or get_or_create. If you don't want to change how you access the values in the templates either, then it seems like a good way would be in the view. Before rendering the template, check if the preferences are None. If they are, create the default record using `UserPreferences` model.

Comment: I was looking for some low-level (model related) solution, but thanks @Jarad, this is almost exactly what I've done yesterday to walkaround this problem (just not in the views directly). If I find some time I'll post an answer about what I found out in the meantime. In short: looks like there is no easy way to accomplish this without going really "low".